# Is there a way to send some procesess with known pid in background?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

I am new in Linux and system programming .
I Want to write a c program which finds processes whose cpu% usage are more than a specific given value and sends them to background.

anybody can help me !
I really appreciate it

Comment: What do you mean by "background"? Are you looking for something like [nice](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/nice.2.html)?

Comment: thanks
I think ,we can send a process to back ground when running in a terminal by Crtl+z
I want to know how can I do this via  shell commands or system calls .

Comment: Just putting them in the background doesn't mean they are going to use less CPU.

Comment: Ctrl+z sends `SIGSTOP` signal to current process. You can send it to any pid using [kill](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) function.

Comment: thanks a lot for your attention,but this has nothing to do with better performance or load balancing.
When we use a 'ps' command There is a '[+] ' in the status of the process which means that this process is in foreground , i just need a command/function to send that process(pid) to background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that what you're asking is that you want to detect if a process is using X amount of CPU and if so, take it off the CPU for a while. There's a piece of software already that does this: It's called the kernel. I'm not aware of any way to programatically take another process off CPU unless that other program supports an external interface to reduce its load.

Most likely what you really want to do is configure the `nice` and other scheduler parameters of the running process so the kernel is more like to to take it off CPU when another program needs to do work.

But what underlying problem are you *really* trying to solve here? Maybe if you tell us that we can offer an alternate solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but this has nothing to do with better performance or load balancing.
When we use a 'ps' command There is a '[+] ' in the status of the process which means that this process is in foreground , i just need a command/function to send that process(pid) to background.

Comment: @Sina: You really have no idea what you're talking about. Listen to the people who are trying to find out what you need so they can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at source code of process managament utilities like:

- [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=downloads)
- top (standard unix command)
- ps (standard unix command)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, You can't.

Background management ensures the shell. So, the `&` is interpreted for example by /bin/bash command. When pressed CTRL-Z, the kernel stopping your current fg-job, and again *by your shell* you can send it into background.

*Youre looking for the way how to remote control the shell what running some program in fg. I don't know any 'remote-controling' way.*

Ofc, here are alternative solutions, for example:

- use the `screen` command, and you can recall the specific screen into your terminal, and can manually send process into bg.
- or you can use some screen-sharing utility, to overtake a specific terminal and CTRL-Z, bg
- or, you can patch bash and adding remote control functionality. ;)

or, here is something what i don't know. ;) - hm, maybe `trap` some user-signal handling code in the  /etc/profile?

You can read a bit about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group

Honestly, after a half hour of thinking I don't get any idea why you want *remotely* (from the another terminal - by its PID) send some processes from the fg into the bg. Give me no sense.

Can you please tell, what you want achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to reduce process priority, but I not sure it's good idea.

We send process to background generally to free shell's prompt.

Comment: thanks for your answer,
When we use a 'ps' command There is a '[+] ' in the status of the process which means that this process is in foreground , i just need a command/function to send that process(pid) to background.

Comment: @Sina *Why* do you want send the process to background, what purpose do you try to achieve? It's obviously not for sake ps will display it with "+" :)))

Answer (score 0):

The "+" means that the program "is in the foreground process group".  I don't believe, however, that this state at all affects the process's scheduling.

However, you can change it with `tcsetpgrp`.

From the man page:  "The function tcsetpgrp() makes the process group with process group ID pgrp the foreground process group on the terminal associated to fd, which must be the controlling terminal  of the  calling  process, and still be associated with its session.  Moreover, pgrp must be a (non-empty) process group belonging to the same session as the calling process."

By my reading, you just call this function and make the shell (or some other program) be the foreground process.